# Rules of when a post is made community wiki need to be clear, prominent

Tags: feature-request, edits, community-wiki

I had a question on Code Review go Community Wiki due to too many edits.  I didn't see anything about those rules and recommendations when I was posting or editing my question.

It would be good to put a little something on the "Ask a question" page with information about the triggers and rules. It might also be beneficial to put that kind of info somewhere prominent in the "edit" dialogue. It might cut down on posts that trigger CW, if volume is even an issue of concern for CW.

I'd like to think that if I'd had some warning about this policy or a popup that says "you've only got 1 edit left before you trigger CW" I would have avoided it.  [Code Reviews' About page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about) doesn't even mention Community Wiki or actions that might land your question under it.

It is hard to follow the rules if you don't know what they are.

Is there a page where such policies are available?  If so, maybe there should be a link to it on "ask" and "edit" pages.  I think that this would make a great website even better.

Comment: Link to the question please?